# Nokogiri: Slop access a node named name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse a xml that looks like this:

```
<lesson>
  <name>toto</name>
  <version>42</version>
</lesson>
```

Using `Nokogiri::Slop`.

I can access lesson easily through `lesson.version` but I cannot access `lesson.name`, as name refer in this case to the name of the node (lesson).

Is there any way to access the child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `search` and give the node a xpath or css selector:

```
doc.lesson.search('name').first
```

Comment: No.. Question is about `Slop`.

Comment: It is still `Slop` mixed with regular selectors.

Comment: Yes. But I am following *The Slop decorator implements method_missing such that methods may be used instead of CSS or XPath.* :-) No issue, you are correct.

Comment: This is a correct answer. The problem with Slop is that the Nokogiri methods conflict with potential element names. It's best to bite the bullet and just learn CSS Selectors and/or XPath.

Answer (score 2):

As a variant you could try this one:

```
doc.lesson.elements.select{|el| el.name == "name"}
```

Why? Just because of this benchmarks:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'benchmark'

str = '<lesson>
  <name>toto</name>
  <version>42</version>
</lesson>'

doc = Nokogiri::Slop(str)

n = 50000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("select") { n.times do; doc.lesson.elements.select{|el| el.name == "name"}; end }
  x.report("search") { n.times do; doc.lesson.search('name'); end }
end
```

Which gives us the result:

```
#=>           user     system      total        real
#=> select 1.466000   0.047000   1.513000 (  1.528153)
#=> search 2.637000   0.125000   2.762000 (  2.777278)
```

Comment: Add mine too.. Let me see the *drawback of meta programming* .. :-)

Comment: The drawback is `el.name` doesn't work, casts `'method_missing': undefined method 'name' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x251d390>` ;)

Comment: Or maybe mine is bad :(

Comment: I think the benchmark might change for bigger input and besides, Ruby is not about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Do a bit *hack* using *meta programming*.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::Slop <<-HTML
<lesson>
  <name>toto</name>
  <version>42</version>
</lesson>
HTML


name_val = doc.lesson.instance_eval do
  self.class.send :undef_method, :name
  self.name
end.text
p name_val # => toto
p doc.lesson.version.text # => '42'
```

[`Nokogiri::XML::Node#name`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-name) is a method defined to get the names of `Nokogiri::XML::Node`. Just for some moment, remove the method from the class `Nokogiri::XML::Node` in the scope of `#instance_eval`.

Comment: I love it, and there is use cases where this would be better, however, in this specific case, I prefer the one-liner :)